# FileMaker 17 Data API missing fieldData

Tags: rest, filemaker

I'm doing a simple HTTP POST find to the new FileMaker 17 DataAPI /REST service:

```
https://{{server}}/fmi/data/v1/databases/{{db}}/layouts/{{layout}}/_find
```

and passing this in the request body:

```
{
    "query":
    [
    {"isActive":"=X", "omit":"false"}   
    ]       
}
```

I get back the following:

```
{
    "response": {
        "data": [
            {
                "fieldData": {},
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "64420",
                "modId": "0"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {},
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "64419",
                "modId": "0"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {},
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "64413",
                "modId": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it appears that I'm only getting back the recordid's associated with the query and the fieldData for that item is missing? I not understainding why there is no column name/value in the fieldData?

I've been looking through: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/17/en/dataapi/index.html#perform-a-find-request but it's not helpful at all and makes no mention/nor provides a list of tags that can be passed alongside the "query" json array

Comment: Are there any fields on the layout your are querying?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the fields you want to access on the layout? FileMaker Data API will give you values from only the fields that you have physically added to the layout.

Have you tried [fmRESTor](http://fmrestor.com)? It's easier to learn and use especially for someone who has no or little experience with accessing FileMaker data from within PHP.